# css rule skipped by browser

Tags: css, browser

Ok, this might look like another stupid question, but I cant find answer.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2kRJv/) fiddle:

Remove `#Navigation` in CSS declaration here:

```
#Navigation .stretch {
...
}
```

so it becomes:

```
.stretch {
...
}
```

Why browser (chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m) ignore this rule?

I have tested also on firefox.

Probably it is not CSS priorities issue, because DevTools neither FireBug doesn't show it entirely. Not even overlined.

Thanks

EDIT: Many thanks guys! I couldn't see those crossed rules before, I was scrolling trough several times, in devTools and in fireBug and solving such a misserable "simple" problem for more than hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rule defined only with `.stretch` selector is less specific than `#navigator li`, and it's not applied even if defined later on cascade. Thus display will be ever `inline`

Comment: And why it is not over-lined in FireBug nor DevTools. And width: 100%; is also skipped even there inst any more specific selector defining width of li.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't ignored, it is overruled by `#Navigation li` because that selector is more specific. It sets `display` to `inline` (instead of your intended `inline block`).

You can easily spot this when you 'inspect element' in Chrome. It shows the styles of the element, and crosses out the overruled styles.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I can see it now.. I dont know why I couldnt find it before. I was desperate after one hour of solving such a basic issue :/

Comment: We all have that problem sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `#Navigation li` has higher specificity than `.stretch` since it contains an `id` selector.

The reason you do not see it is because it is empty and you most likely select the previous element (*on jsfiddle code*).

If you select the empty `li` from firebug it shows it is overriden.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I can see it now.. I dont know why I couldnt find it before. I was desperate after one hour of solving such a basic issue :/